# Assembly Resolve

Tags: .net, dll, assemblies

We create a plugin for a software that was built for .NET 3.5. In this plugin, we reference a third party .DLL that works for .NET 3.5. The main software is now built to .NET 4.0 and the third party .DLL has been split up into two .DLL.

What we want to avoid is having two seperate solutions with almost the exact same code (one built to .NET 4.0 referencing the 4.0 DLLs and one built to 3.5 referencing the 3.5 DLLs). Not all of our customers are going to upgrade to the newest version of the software we create plugins for right away, some may wait years.

**QUESTION EDITED**:

Is there any way to continue to build to .Net 3.5 referencing the 3.5 DLL, and then at run time perform some assembly resolve to load the two .Net 4.0 DLLs in the place of the original one?

We want/need to keep building to a 3.5 framework so that previous versions of the main software will continue to load our plugin. If we build to 4.0 then the older versions will give an error when trying to load our plugin because its build to a later framework.

Comment: Have you actually tried this or are you just guessing there might be a problem?  If you did, what *exactly* is the error message?

Comment: When I try to load a 4.0 plugin with an older version of the software, I get these errors:

Cannot load assembly. Error details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not 
load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\*******\Documents\Visual Studio 
2010\Projects\RandomProjects\A2013Testing\bin\Debug\A2013Testing.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a 
runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
File name: 'file:///C:\Users\*******\Documents\Visual Studio 
2010\Projects\RandomProjects\A2013Testing\bin\Debug\A2013Testing.dll'
   at System.Reflection..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime

That's crystal clear, your EXE loaded an earlier version of the CLR.  Only the .NET 4 version of the CLR knows how to load an assembly that was built to target 4.  The metadata format has changed in 4, the old CLR doesn't know how to read it.

Either rebuild your EXE to target 4 as well or provide a app.exe.config file that forces your program to run with the newer version of the CLR.  It should look like this:

```
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Some testing is required, .NET 4 is highly compatible but it does have some bug fixes that you might accidentally rely on.

Comment: It's not our executable, the executable is trying to load our DLL. The executable is built with 4.0 and previous executables are built with 3.5. We're trying to make our DLL compatible with both. The 4.0 executable will load a 3.5 DLL just fine, but our 3.5 DLL needs to reference a third party 4.0 reference for this version, and the 3.5 DLL for the earlier versions.

Comment: Only the EXE determines what version of the CLR will be loaded.  Because it starts first.  If you get this exception then you can be sure that it is the EXE that causes the problem.  And that it was built to target 3.5  The only way to get any 4.0 DLLs loaded is to force the EXE to load CLR version 4.  Which requires it either to be built to target 4 or this .exe.config file.  You probably need to talk to the owner of the EXE to sort this out, they might not necessarily be happy about it.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is exactly the same (iow both 1 assembly), there is no issue loading a .NET 3.5 library in the .NET 4 runtime. (I do this a lot in IronScheme, because I am lazy to build on VS2010).